# why a returned char can't be directly assigned by another char in one simple expression

Tags: c++

when I compile the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

char retChar(){
    return 'c';
}

int main(){
    retChar() = 'f';
}
```

I got the following errors:

```
modify.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
modify.cpp:8:14: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

I have searched similar questions to this error, but the answers just seem to be situation specific. And I didn't find the answer to my question yet.(maybe somewhere else?)

=======================================add=======================================

but in the situation below:

```
#include <iostream>

class int_Bag{
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    int_Bag(const int x, const int y);
    int_Bag(const int_Bag&c);
    int_Bag& operator =(const int_Bag &c){
        std::cout<< "copy assignment constructor called\n";
        a = c.a;
        b = c.b;
        return *this;
    }

    ~int_Bag();

    void debug();
};

int_Bag::int_Bag(const int x, const int y):a(x),b(y){}

int_Bag::~int_Bag(){
    std::cout<< "destructor called\n";
}

int_Bag::int_Bag(const int_Bag&c):a(c.a),b(c.b){
        std::cout<< "copy constructor called\n";
}

int_Bag getBag(const int_Bag &c){
    return c;
}

void int_Bag::debug(){
    std::cout << a <<"," << b << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int_Bag *bag1 = new int_Bag(3,4);
    int_Bag *bag2 = new int_Bag(5,6);
    std::cout<< "assignment expression begins\n";
    getBag(*bag1) = *bag2;
    bag1->debug();
    delete bag1;
    delete bag2;
}
```

this program just compile and run well:

```
assignment expression begins
copy constructor called
copy assignment constructor called
destructor called
3,4
destructor called
destructor called
```

We can see from the results that, when getBag() is being executing, a temporary object is created by calling copy constructor. So I think for the first situation, that assignment doesn't work is not simply due to the fact that the returned char is temporary.

Why assignment `getBag(*bag1) = *bag2;`works here?

What is the difference between these two situations for assignment expression?

I suppose that, for the second situation, the whole assignment expression is divided into two steps: first to call getBag() then second the copy assignment is called to copy *bag2 to the newly created temporary object returned by getBag(). However, in first situation, retChar() returns a rvalue(also temporary) which can only appear on the RHS of an assignment as @Jonathan Leffler said.

The first situation stands alone just seems to be stupid question maybe(I see those negative remarks). Those questions I just added are actually what I am really confused about.

Looking forward to receiving comments on my supposal and other anwsers.

(from a c++ beginner ^^)

Comment: It's about the logical as saying `'a' = 'b'`

Comment: ... Because you are writing duff code

Comment: What could that possibly mean?

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, I couldn't agree with you more. I just didn't express my question accurately.

Comment: 'Duff code' is distinct from Duff's Device; it's real English (as in, English English, and distinct from, say, American English) for 'bad code'.

Comment: Have you used [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on the code?  Can you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I only used valgrind to check heap leaks(quite unfamiliar with it). For this program valgrind gives these messages:  `total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 16 bytes allocated` , when I rerun valgrind with -v option, it gives information on addresses which I don't understand...:( you want me to add the results valgrind give to the question?

Comment: No; it gives a clean bill of health.  See my amended answer.  Not a definitive statement, but strong pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Original question

You can't assign to the result of a function like that.  The function returns an r-value, something that can only appear on the RHS of an assignment.  Contrast with an l-value which is something that can be assigned to.

If you really wanted to (you probably don't, though) you could write:

```
char *retChar(){
    static char c = 'c';
    return &c;
}

int main(){
    *retChar() = 'f';
}
```

And now you've modified the variable inside the function `retChar()`.

---

#### Amended question

This code does a more thorough job instrumenting your example:

```
#include <iostream>

class int_Bag
{
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    int_Bag(const int x, const int y);
    int_Bag(const int_Bag&c);
    int_Bag& operator =(const int_Bag &c){
        std::cout<< "copy assignment constructor called:\nold";
        this->debug();
        std::cout << "new";
        c.debug();
        a = c.a;
        b = c.b;
        return *this;
    }

    ~int_Bag();
    void debug() const;
};

int_Bag::int_Bag(const int x, const int y) : a(x), b(y)
{
    std::cout << "basic(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
}

int_Bag::~int_Bag()
{
    std::cout << "destructor called";
    this->debug();
}

int_Bag::int_Bag(const int_Bag &c) : a(c.a), b(c.b)
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor called";
    this->debug();
}

int_Bag getBag(const int_Bag &c)
{
    std::cout << "getBag returns";
    c.debug();
    return c;
}

void int_Bag::debug() const
{
    std::cout << "(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int_Bag *bag1 = new int_Bag(3, 4);
    int_Bag *bag2 = new int_Bag(5, 6);

    std::cout << "assignment expression begins\n";
    getBag(*bag1) = *bag2;
    std::cout << "assignment expression ended\n";
    bag1->debug();
    delete bag1;
    delete bag2;
}
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
basic(3,4)
basic(5,6)
assignment expression begins
getBag returns(3,4)
copy constructor called(3,4)
copy assignment constructor called:
old(3,4)
new(5,6)
destructor called(5,6)
assignment expression ended
(3,4)
destructor called(3,4)
destructor called(5,6)
```

The value `5,6` is assigned to the temporary created/returned by `getBag()`, but is then destroyed. None of that affects the original `3,4` value in `*bag1`. The (anonymous) object created by `getBag()` is usable until the end of the full expression it appears in, but not beyond, so the whole assignment is still very dubious.

I was compiling with G++ 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks, or G++ 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.10, in both cases with the options:

```
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror intbag.cpp -o intbag
```

There was not the slightest murmur from the compilers, nor was [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) 3.8.1 in the slightest perturbed by the memory access patterns.

I think C++ gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot, or some such mixed metaphor.

Comment: He could also do it with references and avoid the pointer syntax ... but I agree, I don't think that is really the end goal.

Comment: Yes; there's more than one way to do it, but it still doesn't really bear much thinking about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just edited my question to be clear enough. Can you  help to review the question for some more comments?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very clear and through out demonstrating example! Last question, is it possible to overload assignment operator to char type in order to make the assignment in first program just behavior like in the second program? (The answer is not in my mind -_-, because that is how C++ grammars are defined to be)

Comment: I think I'm correct in saying "No, you can't overload the assignment operators for the built-in types".  I'd be surprised indeed if I was wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You are attempting to modify a temporary (an rvalue).  That is not possible.

You can accomplish your goal in a few ways, but the best one likely is this:

```
int main()
{
    char c = retChar();
    c = 'f';
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

You refer to code that has `getObject() = something`.  That code is likely written in some form that is similar to this:

```
char& getChar()
{
    static char c = 'c';
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    getChar() = 'f';
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

This returns a reference (not a temporary).  When you assign it to `'f'`, the value of the `c` variable in `getChar` becomes `'f'`.

Comment: The other reason for me to ask this question is that I found in another program where a returned class obeject can be placed as left operand in an assignment expression like: getObject() = anotherObject. But this expression just compile well, and I see that the returned temporary object is modified by copy assignment constructor I defined explicitly and is destroyed by destructor when that expression is executed over. So I just got confused why this assignment can work on objects but not on char type data as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you return a reference, you can modify it.  This is likely what is happening in the code you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign a character to a function, which isn't allowed!

I'm not sure why you think this might be allowed, or why you want to do it...

Comment: `retChar` is a function. `retChar()` is a function-call expression. `retChar() = foo;` is not an attempt to assign to a function, it's an attempt to assign to the value returned by the function call.

Comment: @Casey - sure, but that wasn't what the question was when I answered it. The question poster has edited his question since then.

Answer (score -1):

`retChar()` is a function. Functions are not like variables; they cannot be assigned to values. Your `retChar()` function `returns` a char that you can use in your main method. For example you could do:

```
char myChar = retChar();
```

and `myChar` would then be equal to `f`.

If you are finding yourself confused with these concepts then try having a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Comment: Nice recommendations.

Comment: `retChar` is a function. `retChar()` is a function-call expression. `retChar() = foo;` is not an attempt to assign to a function, it's an attempt to assign to the value returned by the function call.